# Problems generating Blob from Uint8Array

Tags: lightning-aura-components, binarydata, lightning-web-security

Regularly, outside of LWC environment when I type the following code

```
const a = new Uint8Array([95, 96, 97]);
const b = new Blob([a], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
b.text().then(out => console.log(out)
// _`a
```

But inside the LWC environment, this is the output I get

```
b.text().then(out => console.log(out)
// 95, 96, 97
```

This makes it impossible to generate binary files for download.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I have Lightning Web Security (beta) turned on.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I took a moment to build an app using your code, both in [LWC OSS](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/HzLFjNE5d6CqNcN6y7SB/src/app.js) and as a [Salesforce LWC](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/8174d1ffb87a44edd48240d44090f6fe), it works correctly in both cases. Perhaps are you doing something wrong elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for the answer. I just randomly put a break point in my code and typed this in the console just for testing purposes. That's the result I got.
The only thing I did was check the "Use Lightning Web Security (beta) for Lightning web components"  checkbox.

Comment: FYI, this is fixed and available in Spring 22 orgs. You should be able to move forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

---

This has now been patched in the Spring 22 sandboxes and Scratch Orgs. I have verified that the the decoding now works as expected.

---

This is a bug in LWS, and should be reported. I'm still nailing down the exact details, but here's what I know so far; I've had to deduce all this information strictly from in-browser source code, so I apologize if the explanation seems unclear.

The LWS model works through two mechanisms. The first are called "distortions", in which any access to a property is filtered through a list of replacement functions that are called. So, when you access a property on a red proxy, it either calls a [distorted](https://github.com/salesforce/lwsec-docs-mirror/) method or the original method, depending on if there are security concerns. For example, `innerHTML` is distorted so that it becomes impossible to inject script tags into a DOM element.

The second mechanism is where it takes unsanitized "blue" values and converts them to sanitized "red" values. It stores these conversions into two WeakMap objects, one that stores the blue value as the key, and the red value as the value, and the other, which stores the red value as the key, and the blue value as the value. This is a performance optimization that makes it far faster than Locker Service, which has to filter values every time they are accessed.

The symbol `a` in your code ends up pointing to a red proxy with the blue key of `Uint8Array([95,96,97])` and the red value of the toString representation `"95,96,97"`. So far, everything is running as it should. `a` is still a `Uint8Array`, but with a mapping internally to the red value `"95,96,97"`, as a string.

Next, we call `new Blob([a], { type: "application/octet-stream" })`. The second parameter is no problem, it gets converted to a red value that matches the blue value, as no sanitation is needed. The first, however, is a problem. We have a blue value Array with a blue Uint8Array, and because we're distorting the method, we need the red values.

What ends up happening is that the blue Array gets converted to a red Array, and in the process, every blue element gets converted to a red element, which, as we stated earlier, was `"97,98,99"`.

After conversion to the red values, we end up with the Blob constructor seeing:

```
new Blob(["95,96,97"], { type: "application/octet-stream" })
```

We can prove this by examining the value of `b`, where we notice that `b.size` is 8, not 3, as expected. After that, the text method is called, and that red value is ultimately given to the Promise.

This answer does not yet provide a solution, but I will be exploring workarounds to this situation, as well as reporting the bug to salesforce.com so it can be fixed or a workaround documented. For now, Blob appears to be unusable given this bug.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this, I'll mark this as answered, and will link this Question to a support ticket.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I've created case 41822022, and will update this when I get more info.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes I did some more debugging, the old answer was indeed inaccurate. I have provided a more accurate description of the problem. There appears to be no workaround at this time, except to use another method (perhaps decoding a base64 string?) and avoiding Typed Arrays altogether.

Comment: I cannot use a base64 string at the moment, I have written my own Excel exporter and ZipContainer. To create the Zip file, I add every character of the Excel sheet to the Uint8Array using charCodeAt and then create the Zip File using the Blob. The Excel Exporter functionality will need to be disabled within SalesForce for the time being but again, thanks for all the help with this.
For more info, see: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/latest/community-modules/csv-export/src/csvExport/zipContainer.ts#L191